# Room availability

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I was wondering what would the best way to manage availability for rooms or beds like in a hostel (Saas).
I was thinking about using MySQL and Elasticsearch.
What would be the best schema for the rooms/bed table and availability table?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a note that "poll" like questions "what is the best" are quite discouraged as a question however you've done the right thing be constraining the question significantly to the topic. My answer gives one option of a fairly decent approach however without considering the full scope of every implementation the 'what is the best' isn't answerable. Welcome to DBA stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB-10.5 has a feature [Application Time Periods - WITHOUT OVERLAPS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#without-overlaps) who's example even lists availability for rooms as an example.

The example gives:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE rooms (
 room_number INT,
 guest_name VARCHAR(255),
 checkin DATE,
 checkout DATE,
 PERIOD FOR p(checkin,checkout),
 PRIMARY KEY (room_number, p WITHOUT OVERLAPS)
 );
```

As an example syntax.

Attempting to overlap a booking will result in an error:

```
INSERT INTO rooms VALUES 
 (1, 'Regina', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-03'),
 (2, 'Cochise', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-05'),
 (1, 'Nowell', '2020-10-03', '2020-10-07'),
 (2, 'Eusebius', '2020-10-04', '2020-10-06');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2-2020-10-06-2020-10-04' for key 'room_number'
```

So in your application you need to catch the duplicate key error as an exception and treat that as already booked.

Comment: Very interesting! I was more concern about how to manage the availability in case of: 
- the the prices change depending on a date 
- if a bed would be block for a period?
- I was planning to have a calendar of 2-3 years on a 10000 beds
thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Multiple blocks are one option, however it might overly complicate some aspects dealing with a single booking. There is some interesting tradeoffs there, however for a more complete answer consider asking it as a separate question and showing more detail as to the operations/queries on this table. Alternately just try it one way and if you run into troubles then ask and you'll have all the background information.

Comment: Very Clear I will look into that

Comment: Also cool which I didn't notice when I answered this is the [DELETE BY PORTION](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#deletion-by-portion) where you can cancel a day of the booking and have the MariaDB server autosplit/adjust rows as required.